# Duplicate project names (hierarchical vs flat project structure) in SonarQube 4.5.5

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.5 and I need to configure several projects which have the same name, but whose contents are different.

What happens is that the projects belong to different departments and, although the names are the same, the files are potentially different and therefore must be kept separate.

As far as I know, SonarQube has a flat project structure and what I really need is a hierarchical structure.

How can I solve this?

Many thanks for any help.

Regards,
Nuno Guerreiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names can be the same; it is only the keys which must be different.

Analyze each department's project separately, and then if you need to unify them for a top-level view, use the commercial [Views plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) to do that.

Comment: Development for these projects is made in Eclipse and we're using the SonarQube plug-in for Eclipse. How is the association between the Eclipse project and SonarQube project made? Is it via project key or project name? I suspect it is via project key, but not sure and couldn't find an answer on the plug-in documentation

Comment: For the latest version of SonarLint for Eclipse, there is no association. That'll be coming back soon, though, and will likely be made by key as in the past.